# When using Sequelize, do I have to follow their table/field name patterns?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Node and Sequelize to access an existing database. Now I'm trying to create an n:m association in Sequelize, but I'm having some trouble with the names of the fields. 
According to the Sequelize Docs:

```js
Foo.belongsToMany(Bar, { through: 'foo_bar', sourceKey: 'name', targetKey: 'title' });
// This creates a junction table `foo_bar` with fields `fooName` and `barTitle`
```

But I already have the table and I don't want to change the name of the keys to `fooName` and `barTitle`. Is that a way to use only `name` and `title` instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your definition according to BelongsToMany specification in the [sequelize docs](https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations)

```
User.belongsToMany(Project, { as: 'Tasks', through: 'worker_tasks', foreignKey: 'userId', otherKey: 'projectId'})
```

Replace **sourceKey** with **foreignKey** and **targetKey** with **otherKey**